# How to debug docker run command

Tags: docker

I am issuing a command like below:

```
docker run -d myvm script.sh 10
```

The problem is, it is not working. So I want to see what happened when script.sh was executed or whether it got executed at all or not. The script is supposed to write something in a text file. But I am not getting any idea what is the error. When I login to the container as a user and execute the script myself, I do get proper result. So,

```
docker run -it myvm
```

and then,

```
script.sh 10
```

works fine. So how can I see what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

if i correctly understand what you ask, I think you are confusing about this command. Indeed, docker run command is applied to an image and not to a script.

Please refer to the following documentation :
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run.

Now if you want to execute the script they are several ways to do that. Two examples:

1. CLI:

copy the script.sh and execut it if the container is running:

```
docker cp my_container_id:/script/path/host/script.sh /tmp/script.sh
docker exec -i my_container_id chmod +x /tmp/script && /bin/bash /tmp/script.sh 10
```

2. Dockerfile:

Create a Dockerfile :
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/
With Dockerfile you customize your container based on one image.
Create a file called Dockerfile and add:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ADD /path/host/script.sh /tmp/script.sh
CMD [/tmp/script, "10"]
```

For example we use the ubuntu image and copy the script on the /tmp/ path in container and then we execut it at the boot.

Now you can build your image :

```
docker build -t foo /path/to/dockerfile/Dockerfile
```

and run :

```
docker run -d foo
```

Edit:
This answer no longer fits with the initial question.

Comment: Okay you edited your question. My answer no longer fits.

Comment: Can I apply docker kill to docker exec? In my case I am applying docker run and then if the execution takes too long then I kill the container to release the resources.

Comment: I edited right after post because I missed the -d option. Nothing more.

Comment: Sure, docker kill is applied to an container. See which containers are executed with docker ps and kill it. But you can also add a timeout on docker run command with --stop-timeout and control the maximum cpu/ram... you want allocate. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/ , i hope this answers your question.